# Python Mock - Can't Figure Out How to Mock This Class/Function

Tags: python, mocking

I have this class and function to simply copy files from one place to another. As I am new to Mocking, I can't figure out how to properly test this, any assistance would be greatly appreciated, (note CFG_Dict is a dictionary with values I pass), note that this is an example and i have **init** that is used for multiple functions in this class.

```
from shutil import copy
import os
from pathlib2 import Path


class FileMover(object):

    def __init__(self, cfg_dict):

        self.copyto = str(Path(cfg_dict['GENERAL']['filecopylocation']))
        self.worklocation = str(Path(cfg_dict['GENERAL']['fileworklocation']))

    def run_file_mover(self, filename):
        filename = str(Path(filename))

        try:
            copy(filename, self.copyto)
        except ValueError:
            raise

        return str(Path('%s/%s' % (self.copyto, os.path.basename(filename))))
```

Edit:

I made some more modifications and this is my new code for testing,

```
class TestMover(TestCase):

    def test_file_move(self):
        cfg_test = {'GENERAL': {'filecopylocation': '/test/temp/', 'fileworklocation': '/test/'},
                    'SFTP': {'sftpserver': 'localhost', 'sftpport': '22', 'sftpuser': 'test', 'sftppw': 'test', 'sftpdestination': 'test'}}

        with mock.patch('generate_reports.tools.file_mover.copy') as test_copy_function:
            FileMover(cfg_test).run_file_mover("foo")
            assert test_copy_function.called
```

Comment: It's not valid. All you are testing is that your mock is returning the value you said it should return. You aren't testing your original code in anyway.

Comment: The main use of `mock` here would be to mock `file_mover.copy` so that calling `FileMover().run_file_mover("foo")` doesn't actually try to copy anything.

Comment: @chepner any chance I could get a better sample with this method?

Comment: @chepner I added a new sample based on your suggestion to do a copy, does this make more sense? Also, what other asserts should I used to improve the test?